# How to reset hbase and zookeeper

Tags: hbase, apache-zookeeper

Frequently a development cluster HBase is unable to contact zookeeper after I have shut it down.  I would like to have a "nuke" switch to be able to simply blow away hbase related zk nodes and be able to start from scratch.

What is the way to do such a reset?

BTW Here is a message when attempting to connect via hbase shell:

```
19:28:09/bin $hbase shell
2014-12-03 00:23:28,687 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: hadoop.native.lib is deprecated. Instead, use io.native.lib.available
HBase Shell; enter 'help<RETURN>' for list of supported commands.
Type "exit<RETURN>" to leave the HBase Shell
Version 0.98.0-hadoop2, r1565492, Thu Feb  6 16:46:57 PST 2014

hbase(main):001:0> list
TABLE
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
2014-12-03 00:24:06,576 ERROR [main] zookeeper.ZooKeeperWatcher: hconnection-0x357c5b44, quorum=localhost:2181, baseZNode=/hbase Received unexpected KeeperException, re-throwing exception
org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase/hbaseid
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:99)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:51)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.exists(ZooKeeper.java:1041)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper.exists(RecoverableZooKeeper.java:199)
```

Answer (score 0):

As you said hard reset of Zookeeper is the only solution.

Comment: I changed the hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir and restarted zk/hbase.. however the above problem still exists.